# Update старого приложения в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Есть мобильное приложение, опубликованное в маркете, которое необходимо обновить до совершенно нового. Приложение старое, писалось еще под 2-е версии андроида. По сути от старых исходников мне ничего не надо, поэтому я хочу создать новый проект и использовать тот же самый packageName. Вопрос: не возникнут ли какие-нибудь подводные камни? Нормально ли накатится потом обнова, если я установлю versionCode побольше, подпишусь тем же ключом, установлю minSdk=15, ну и packageName соответствующий.

Comment: Проблемы могут быть например из за разницы в форматах сохраняемых данных

Comment: Тоже думал об этом, но до этого еще далеко, там увидим

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если packageName будет тем же и подпишитесь тем же сертификатои/ключем, то с обновлением приложения не будет никаких проблем. Единственное из за minSdk=15 гуг плей при заливке нового апк предупредит что он подходит не для всех устройств на которых была установлена старая версия и предложит сохранить обе версии приложения, при этом старая версия будет доступна только на устройствах не совместимых с новым.

Comment: Cпасибо, Вы развеяли тень сомнений:)

Answer (score 2):

Никаких подводных камней не должно быть, но новая версия будет недоступна для старых девайсов, что в принципе логично

PS: надеюсь подпись тоже сохранилась :)

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв!

Comment: ой я повторился ... разница в ответах миннута )